# Erro mark/reset not supported ao executar arquivo .wav

Tags: java, áudio

Criei um botão que, quando pressionado, reproduzisse um som, mas estou tendo problemas pois ele lança essa exceção:

> "mark/reset not supported",

Não faço ideia do que pode ser e nem como resolver, alguém pode me ajudar?

Criei uma classe exemplo pra vocês me ajudar:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;
import javax.sound.sampled.DataLine;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineEvent;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineListener;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Teste {
    private static String somPath = "src/pistola_som.wav";
    private static FileInputStream fis;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        fis = new FileInputStream(somPath);
        tocarSom(fis, false);
    }
    public static void tocarSom(final InputStream somPath, final boolean restart) {
        try {
            //Obtem os dados sonoros
            AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(somPath);

            //Carrega o formato do audio e cria uma linha
            AudioFormat af = ais.getFormat();
            DataLine.Info dataLineInfo = new DataLine.Info(Teste.class, ais.getFormat(),
                    ((int)ais.getFrameLength() * af.getFrameSize()));

            //Carrega o som para o dispositivo
            Clip clip = (Clip)AudioSystem.getLine(dataLineInfo);
            clip.addLineListener(new LineListener() {

                //Evento do Listener
                public void update(LineEvent e) {
                    if(e.getType() == LineEvent.Type.STOP) {
                        e.getLine().close();
                    }
                }
            });
            clip.open(ais);

            //Tocar som
            if(restart) {
                clip.loop(clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);
            } else {
                clip.loop(0);
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Erro na reprodução do audio:\n" + e.getMessage(), "Zumbi ",
                    JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Por favor, apresente um **[mcve]** para que seja possivel testar o problema.

Comment: pronto, agora diminui o código

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segundo esta [resposta do SOEn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5529906/5524514) e a própria documentação do método [`AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(InputStream)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/AudioSystem.html#getAudioInputStream-java.io.InputStream-), o fluxo que você fornece a este método deve suportar recursos de *marcar/reiniciar*  fluxo.

Para garantir isso, você deve testar se o tipo de `InputStream` que está passando dá este suporte, através do método [`markSupported()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#markSupported--), ou "decorar" como um tipo [`BufferedInputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedInputStream.html):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

    fis = new FileInputStream(somPath);

    BufferedInputStream bufferStream =  new  BufferedInputStream(fis);
    tocarSom(bufferStream, false);
}
```

---

Testando um arquivo `.wav` no método bem mais simples abaixo, funcionou perfeitamente.

```
public static void play(InputStream filename) {

    try {

        Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        BufferedInputStream bufferStream = new BufferedInputStream(filename);
        clip.open(AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(bufferStream));
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        clip.start();

    } catch (InterruptedException | LineUnavailableException | IOException | UnsupportedAudioFileException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Agora deu este erro: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No line matching class Teste supporting format PCM_SIGNED 44100.0 Hz, 16 bit, stereo, 4 bytes/frame, little-endian, and buffers of 211680 to 211680 bytes is supported. será que é por causa do audio?

Comment: @PauloAleixo com o método que adicionei na resposta, funciona normalmente. Esse problema deve ser em outro lugar.